# Rails3: Generating a Model in Custom Generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey Guys, I'm writing a custom Generator(named shcaffold) in Rails 3.0.3, and I'd like it to generate an active_record model(and migration) based on the first argument passed into it(the model's name).

However, I'm getting this error when I run the command:

```
$ rails g shcaffold someclass
   error  active_record [not found]
```

Here's my generator definition, stored in lib/generators/shcaffold/shcaffold_generator.rb:

```
class ShcaffoldGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
   include Rails::Generators::ResourceHelpers
   source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)

   # Run Other Generators
   hook_for :model, :in => :rails, :required => true
end
```

I'm defining the orm in my app's application.rb:

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.orm             :active_record
  g.template_engine :erb
  g.test_framework  :test_unit, :fixture => false
  g.stylesheets     false
end
```

But alas, I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No detailled answer, but you should take inspiration there: https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators

Comment: Cool, this is a good place to start. I suppose I can use migration_template for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another similar question regarding the the `error active_record [not found]` pain in the nether regions =)

Over here: [Rails: hook_for :orm not finding active_record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16367261/rails-hook-for-orm-not-finding-active-record)

How to resolve:

1. Stay within the Rails::Generators namespace

   This already solves most of the not-found issues.
2. configure your generator as a default. (anywhere within the Generators model space)

   ```
   module Rails
     module Generators
       class Railtie < ::Rails::Engine
           if config.respond_to?(:app_generators)
               config.app_generators.orm = :my_own_model
            else
               config.generators.orm = :my_own_model
            end
         end
      end
   end
   ```

And you wont have any further hassles from `rails g` anymore.

nJoy!