# Rails: hook_for :orm not finding active_record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm, generator

I'm writing a custom generator. For the most part, the generator is able to use hooks successfully. For instance,

```
hook_for :resource_route, in: :rails, required: true
```

Invokes `resource_route` as expected. However:

```
hook_for :orm, in: :rails, required: true
```

Returns the error:

```
error  active_record [not found]
```

I'm assuming this is because the `active_record_generator` is located in a dramatically different directory from other generators, such as the `resource_route` generator.

> rails / activerecord / lib / rails / generators / active_record.rb
>
> rails / railties / lib / rails / generators / rails / resource_route /
>   resource_route_generator.rb

Is there a way to get my generator to properly hook active record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually hacked this, only after I managed a dodgy work around using `hook_for` and `remove_hook_for` fiasco. My advise leave it alone it's not worth the trouble.

This way uses much less code for way more result for your effort.

There are a few tricks you may want to use.

1. Stay within the Rails::Generators namespace.

   The folder structure I used was:

   ```
   lib/generators/my_own_model/
                              templates/
                              my_own_model_generator.rb
   ```
2. Set the config in the model for the generator you want to create

   That's all you need to overcome the `error whatever [not found]` headaches.

   Code looks like this

   ```
   require 'rails/generators/active_record/model/model_generator'

   module Rails
     module Generators

       hide_namespace 'my_own_model'

       class Railtie < ::Rails::Engine
         if config.respond_to?(:app_generators)
           config.app_generators.orm = :my_own_model
         else
           config.generators.orm = :my_own_model
         end
       end

       class MyOwnModelGenerator < ActiveRecord::Generators::ModelGenerator
         source_root "#{base_root}/active_record/model/templates" 

            # all public methods will get executed by rails g  

            protected

            # these won't but can be overwritten by sub classes

            private

            # these are still exposed to your templates nifty
       end
     end
   end
   ```
3. The third trick is to hide your generator name. Why is that you ask? Well you may like to know that you won't be needing it anymore.

   ```
   $ rails g model MyNewModel generator:belongs_to my_own:boolean
   ```

You have just created a default generator which you can overwrite again from your template folders. =)

nJoy!

Comment: Next time I write up some custom generators, I'll refer to this. Thanks for the thorough response!

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 5 at least, you need to specify the type of generator (:model, :migration, :application_record)

```
hook_for :orm, as: :model
```